# Sharepoint webhooks: Subscribing to a list

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, webhooks

I'm trying to subscribe an application to a Sharepoint list. The notifications will be sent to the app via webhooks. To do this, you have to make an HTTP POST request to:

```
https://{your-account}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists('{list-guid}')/subscriptions
```

Body:

```
{
    "resource": "{{ URL of the resource Id }}",
    "notificationUrl" : "{{ URL of the endpoint that will process the webhooks }}",
    "expirationDateTime" : "2017-09-27T00:00:00+00"
}
```

The call requires an access token. I obtained the token with curl this way:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id={{ Id of the application registered on Azure Active Directory }}&client_secret={{ Key added on Azure for the app }}&grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https%3A%2F%2F{{ My account }}.sharepoint.com" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ Azure account tenant id}}/oauth2/token"
```

This returns a token that is included as a header in the POST request. Unfortunately, this request failed with error code 401. Body:

```
{ 
    "error_description" : "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."
}
```

I think the problem is not the token, we tried too many times before it stopped throwing errors related to invalid token data.

Is there a way to debug this error? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem was the access token, and we were able to get a correct access token. There are two ways to do it, and these methods work for single-tenant application.

**Method 1: Two steps without sending the Azure credentials (only app credentials)**

Step 1: Request a verification code. 
Access this URL. It will redirect you to the redirect_uri passed in the query string, and the query string of the redirect will include a code that will be used to request the token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{  Tenant id }}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={{ Application id }}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={{ URI of the application }}&response_mode=query&resource={{ Resource that you want to access}}&state=12345
```

Resource example: https%3A%2F%2Fyouraccount.sharepoint.com

Step 2: Request a token

```
 curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={{ Application code }}&code={{ The code received in the last request }}&redirect_uri={{ Same redirect URI }}&resource={{ Same resource}}&client_secret={{ Application key }}" https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ Tenant id }}/oauth2/token
```

**Method 2: One step, sending the Azure credentials**

```
curl -i -X POST -d "grant_type=password&resource={{ Resource id }}&client_id={{ App id }}&username={{ Azure username }}&password={{ Azure password }}" "https://login.windows.net/{{ Tenant id }}/oauth2/token"
```